Again unable to later review skipped low quality posts (answers) reviews, which is normally allowed for other review queues
The issue Unable to later review skipped Low Quality Posts reviews, which is normally allowed for other review queues was previously fixed, but has regressed.
As stated there:

When reviewing [Low quality answers], I accidentally pressed Skip instead of Recommend Deletion. So when I noticed my mistake, I went back by pressing the browser's "go back" button. The problem is that now the item is not reviewable:
[...]
After some testing, I've figured out that it seems to happen every time I press Skip and then visit the review item again, either by pressing the browser's back button, following a link from my review history, or visiting that URL in any other way. However, refreshing the page or even closing the tab and then copy-pasting the URL into a new tab works just fine, so it seems to only happen after having pressed the Skip button.
[...]
This happens only with the [Low quality answers] queue; in other review queues, I can still review an item by navigating back to it after skipping it initially.

This was previously fixed, per this staff answer:

This will be fixed in the next build.
Each queue has a general filter to exclude non-skip reviewed tasks when picking new ones, but a handful of queues have cross-validation on post ID. The apparent thought is that we don't want the reviewer handling the same post in multiple queues. (For example, the same post could end up in [First answers] and [Late answers].) Unfortunately, this additional exclusion logic treated skipped tasks as reviews and prevented them from being returned to.

However, the issue is now occurring again. I tried returning to this Low quality posts review task after skipping it, and I got an error message that I wasn't able to review the item - the same error that was pointed out in the older bug report that was later reworded. I was unable to replicate this behavior for other review queues.
Can it please be fixed again?

This doesn't seem to happen on Stack Overflow.
